# How to add Adsense to a website built with GatsbyJS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, adsense, gatsby, head

I'd like to know where I should add the `<script></script>` provided by Google Adsense.

They say to add it into the `<head></head>`, but in Gatsby you have Helmet as `<head>`.

I tried also to add the script inside an html.js file where it's located a `<head>` tag with ``` {``} ``` to escape the `<script>` tag, but it outputs at the top of the website the script content.

**TL;DR: What is the optimal way to add Adsense to a website built with GatsbyJS?**

- I've tried to use the [react adsense package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adsense) but I do not understand how to use it with Gatsby.
- I have tried to add the `<script>` tag to html.js and it doesn't compile.
- If you escape it with ``` {``} ``` you get the script as is, on top of the website.

```
<head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
          />
          {this.props.headComponents}
          {`<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>`}
             {` <script>
                  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
                    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-1540853335472527",
                    enable_page_level_ads: true
                  });
                </script> 
              `}
        </head>
```

source: html.js

**The website should get detected by the Google crawlers.**

Comment: The quotation marks are transformed &quot; in browser. Not sure if there's a fix.

Comment: Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to suppress browser error.

Comment: `<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: '(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({google_ad_client: "something",enable_page_level_ads: true});',
  }}
/>`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to an answer given on Github, finally the problem is solved:

If you want to add Adsense:

- `cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js`
- Add the script but everything inside should be escaped -> {`<some-js-code-here>`}
- In my situation and as an example:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
             <script>
                  {`
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
                      google_ad_client: "ca-pub-1540853335472527",
                      enable_page_level_ads: true
                    });
                  `}
             </script>
```

Comment: Ultimately if you want to verify that Adsense has been added you can control if the `<script>` relative to ads appears -> inside the `<head>` tag you should find something like ```<script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>```

Answer (score 17):

if you are using services like `Netlify` to deploy your website, you can use snippet injection functionality to make this work without touching your source code.

`settings -> build & deploy -> post processing -> snippet injection -> add snippet`

then you can select where you want to add the snippet (script tag). For the `Adsense` this should be before the `</head>`. hope it helps. :)

[image]

Comment: Good one! I do not have to worry about ignoring things on Github

Answer (score 3):

You can find here a nice tutorial on [how to add Google AdSense in Gatsby](https://www.polynique.com/web-development/best-way-to-add-google-adsense-to-gatsby/).

Basically, the suggested way is to implement a Google AdSense Banner using React and including the Google AdSense code in the `gatsby-ssr.js` file.

gatsby-ssr.js file:

```js
const React = require('react')

const HeadComponents = [
  <script
    src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXX"
    crossOrigin="anonymous"
    async
  />,
]

exports.onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }, pluginOptions) => {
  setHeadComponents(HeadComponents)
}
```

AdSense Banner component:

```js
const Banner: React.FC<BannerProps> = ({
  className,
  style,
  layout,
  format,
  client = 'ca-pub-XXXX',
  slot,
  responsive,
  layoutKey,
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []
      adsbygoogle.push({})
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className={clx(container, className)}>
      <ins
        className="adsbygoogle"
        style={style}
        data-ad-layout={layout}
        data-ad-format={format}
        data-ad-client={client}
        data-ad-slot={slot}
        data-ad-layout-key={layoutKey}
        data-full-width-responsive={responsive}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Don't use the gatsby-adsense plugin, it's deprecated.

Full article [here](https://www.polynique.com/web-development/best-way-to-add-google-adsense-to-gatsby/).

Comment: Just a side note, for **Gatsby V2** (with ES6) you will need to use `export const onRenderBody` instead of `exports.onRenderBody`.

Answer (score 2):

To set up Adsense, place the `<script>` tag (without template literals ``` {``} ``` just before your closing `</body>` tag in your `html.js`, like this:

```html
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Then, to place an ad unit, you can either use a pre-built component like [`react-adsense`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adsense) on npm, as you mentioned, or build it yourself.

[This is a useful article](https://malloc.fi/google-adsense-with-gatsby-js) that covers both the setup and the placing of ad units with a component.

Let me know if this works for you or if something isn't clear!

Answer (score 0):

To add Google Adsence in Gatsby you need these three packages

`react-adsense rehype-react gatsby-transformer-remark`

and if you want to know how to implement these packages in your site then checkout [this tutorial](https://www.idesignpixels.com/posts/adsense-in-gatsby)